# SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' - stringify for C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm setting textbox attributes on codebehind, like this:

```
txtTest.Attributes.Add("onchange", string.Format("return txtTest_OnChange(this, '{0}');", strWaterMark));
```

where strWaterMark is a string, which may contain quotes like (**'**) or (**"**).
This then causes js script error. `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'`

is there a way to escape quotes within a string, something like JSON.Stringify?

Comment: strWaterMark.Replace("\'", "\\'");

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver. I was doing it like this .Replace("'", "\'"), silly me.

Comment: In my case, I forgot to close a quote.